# C++: can't modify global variables

Tags: c++, user-interface, global-variables

I'm working on an assignment right now and I've hit a bit of a wall with adding new members of a data group to a linked list. I've googled and looked all over but I haven't been able to find a solution to the problem. The problem is that the 6 variables I've declared globally (customers, and the 5 node type variables) are modified initially when I open a file in Openbutton_Click. But I'm unable to modify the variables later in addconf_Click. Normally I wouldn't post for help but I'm running out of time and can't figure this out. I'm having a lot of trouble formatting this so bear with me please.

Here is the .cpp file that goes with myform.h

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System; 
using namespace System::Windows::Forms; 
using namespace std;

int customers = 0;
node *current;
node *first;
node *last;
node *temp;
node *previous;


[STAThread] 
void Main(array<String^>^ args) { 
Application::EnableVisualStyles(); 
Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

Project1::MyForm form;

Application::Run(%form); 
}
```

This is all in myform.h

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
#include "header.h"

using namespace std;

struct node{
account customer;
node *next;

};

extern int customers;
extern node *current;
extern node *first;
extern node *last;
extern node *temp;
extern node *previous;

private: System::Void Openbutton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
ifstream fin;

openFileDialog1->ShowDialog();

String^ filenname = System::IO::Path::GetFileName(openFileDialog1->FileName);
std::string filename = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(filenname);

fin.open(filename);


if (fin){
    this->label2->Text = "File Opened";
}
else
    this->label2->Text = "Failed to Open File";

String^ menu;
String^ temp;
string input;
string name;
string numstr;
string pinstr;
string balstr;
int num;
int pin;
float bal;

first = new node;

getline(fin, input);

numstr = input.substr(0, 3);

stringstream convert3(numstr);
convert3 >> num;


name = input.substr(8, 16);

name.erase(name.find_last_not_of(" \n\r\t") + 1);

pinstr = input.substr(24, 4);


balstr = input.substr(30, 7);



stringstream convert(pinstr);
convert >> pin;

stringstream convert2(balstr);
convert2 >> bal;

first->customer.setNum(num);
first->customer.setName(name);
first->customer.setPin(pin);
first->customer.setBal(bal);
first->next = 0;

numstr.clear();
name.clear();
pinstr.clear();
balstr.clear();

current = first;

customers++;

while (fin){
    customers++;
    previous = current;
    current->next = new node;
    current = current->next;

        getline(fin, input);

        numstr = input.substr(0, 3);

        name = input.substr(8, 16);

        name.erase(name.find_last_not_of(" \n\r\t") + 1);

        pinstr = input.substr(24, 4);

        balstr = input.substr(30, 7);

        stringstream convert3(numstr);
        convert3 >> num;

        stringstream convert(pinstr);
        convert >> pin;

        stringstream convert2(balstr);
        convert2 >> bal;


        current->customer.setNum(num);
        current->customer.setName(name);
        current->customer.setPin(pin);
        current->customer.setBal(bal);

    }
    last = previous;
    last->next = 0;
    customers--;
    cout << "All accounts loaded, system ready." << endl;
    // Print and fill the textbox
    current = first;

    menu = "Account List:" + customers + "\r\n " + "Num | Account Holder | Pin | Balance\r\n";


    for (int c = 0; c < customers; c++){
        menu += current->customer.getNum();
        menu += " | ";
        temp = gcnew String(current->customer.getName().c_str());
        menu += temp;
        menu += " | ";
        menu += current->customer.getPin();
        menu += " | $";
        menu += current->customer.getBal();
        menu += "\r\n";

        if (current->next != 0){
            current = current->next;
        }
        else
            c = customers;
    }


textBox1->Text = gcnew String(menu);
launch->Visible = true;
addCust->Visible = true;
remCust->Visible = true;
refList->Visible = true;
}

private: System::Void addconf_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
int num = -1;
string name = "";
int pin = -1;
float bal = -1;
bool match = false;

string numstr = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(addnumbox->Text);
num = stoi(numstr);
name = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(addnamebox->Text);


name.erase(name.find_last_not_of(" \n\r\t") + 1);
string pinstr = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(addpinbox->Text);
pin = atoi(pinstr.c_str());

string balstr = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(addbalbox->Text);
bal = stof(balstr);

if (num != -1 && pin != -1 && name != "" && bal != -1){

    current = new node;
    last->next = current;
    current->customer.setNum(num);
    current->customer.setName(name);
    current->customer.setPin(pin);
    current->customer.setBal(bal);
    current->next = 0;


    last = current;
    customers = customers + 1;
    num = -1;
    pin = -1;
    name = "";
    bal = -1;


    }


}
```

header.h is here

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class account{
private:
int accNum;
int accPin;
string accName;
float accBal;

public:
void setNum(int num);
void setPin(int pin);
void setName(string name);
void setBal(float bal);
void deposit(float money);
void withdraw(float money);

int getNum();
int getPin();
string getName();
float getBal();
};

void account::setNum(int num){
accNum = num;
}

void account::setPin(int pin){
accPin = pin;
}

void account::setName(string name){
accName = name;
}

void account::setBal(float bal){
accBal = bal;
}

int account::getNum(){
return accNum;
}

int account::getPin(){
return accPin;
}

string account::getName(){
return accName;
}

float account::getBal(){
return accBal;
}

void account::deposit(float money){
accBal = accBal + money;
}

void account::withdraw(float money){
accBal = accBal - money;
}
```

Comment: Did you check if the condition `(num != -1 && pin != -1 && name != "" && bal != -1)` ever evaluates to true? Do you get an error message? or what happens that makes you think it does not work?

Comment: Btw you do not have to post commented code and properly formatting would help to read a lot.

Comment: I've checked it and it does evaluate to true. The reason i think something is broken is because the linked list value never change even though i'm assigning values to them and I'm not able to add new members to the linked list.

Comment: This is  not C++ as the exclusive OR operator, `^`, requires two parameters, so `String^` is not valid.  Also, access modifiers are not allowed before the `class` identifier, e.g. `public class`, is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `customers` as a an int in the header-file. Keep in mind that the header-file is literary pasted into the files it is included in. So you will have many instances of that variable.

The correct way to do it is to define it in a cpp-file, and make it global by using `extern int customers` in your header-file.

The same issue is true for your `nodes`-variables. You must define them in a cpp-file so that they only exist in one place.

However, using global mutable variables like that is almost never a good idea.

Comment: So i went and made the variables extern in the .h and defined them in the .cpp but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a line of code the properly print out the current state of the list. Feel like a complete idiot right now. Thanks to those of you that helped out.